# Skip Ad on Twitter using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, twitter, web-crawler, adblock

Im using selenium to scarpe some data from Search/Lastest from Twitter. 1 small problem is that, when they showing ad, I cant filter them out. I have some way to do that, but struggle and cant find the solution.

1. Ad tweet have no time. I tried this, but it took too long.

```
        try{
            WebElement time = article.findElement(By.xpath(TIME_XPATH));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

2. Ad tweet have view count. Didn't try, but normal tweet dont have view count, so I dont think that gonna work.
3. Ad tweet dont have the keyword text. But then, if i filter by that way, i cant get replies tweet, like replies @ElonMusk.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!